# Deploying Windows 10 in an enterprise - how do I remove the pre-installed apps?

Tags: image, windows-10

I'm trying to deploy some Windows 10 machines at work, and need to remove or disable the pre-installed apps.

For some reason, management feels that the Xbox app and Candy Crush Soda Saga (etc.) shouldn't be installed on a corporate workstation.

We've tried uninstalling them after the fact, but they show up again for any new users logging in, which isn't acceptable.  How do we *really* get rid of these apps from our corporate Windows 10 image?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The easiest method I've found to actually control a Windows 10 image is to edit it with the [Deployment Image Servicing and Management (DISM.exe)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371719%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) tool.

---

In short, you need to:

1. Locate the Windows wim for the image you're deploying.

   - On a Windows 10 installation ISO, for example, the file is: `\sources\install.wim`
2. Create a directory to temporarily mount the wim in.
3. Mount the wim.
4. Make your changes.

   - For the purposes of removing the pre-installed Windows 10 apps, there are actually three different types we need to deal with here - one classic executable, a bunch of [Metro/UWP/Appx applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Windows_Platform_apps), and a bunch of installer shortcuts that Windows 10 forces onto the Start Menu.
   - Seems worth pointing out here that you can [get a list of appx packages from the mounted WIM with DISM](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824882.aspx), if you're not sure what changes you wish to make.
5. Commit the changes and unmount the WIM.

---

In more detail:

1. Locate the Windows wim.

   - I'll be downloading the latest 64 bit, Enterprise version of Windows 10 (SW_DVD5_WIN_ENT_10_1511.1_64BIT_English_MLF_X20-93758.ISO) from Micorosoft's volume licensing portal, and mounting the ISO to `D:`.  (Be sure to mount it with read-write access, of course!)
   - This puts the wim file I want to edit at: `D:\sources\install.wim`. I'll assign that to a PowerShell variable.

     - `$wimfile = "D:\sources\install.wim"`
2. Create a directory to temporarily mount the wim in.

   - I'll use `C:\Temp\W10entDISM`, and assign that to a PowerShell variable as well.

     - `$mountdir = "C:\Temp\W10entDISM"`
3. [Mount the wim with DISM](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825258.aspx).

   - `dism.exe /Mount-Image /ImageFile:$wimfile /Index:1 /MountDir:$mountdir`
4. Make your changes.

   - For the purposes of removing the pre-installed Windows 10 apps, there are actually three different types we need to deal with here - one classic executable, a bunch of Metro/UWP/Appx applications, and a bunch of installer shortcuts that Windows 10 forces onto the Start Menu.

     1. The classic executable, OneDrive Installer

        - Windows 10 has an executable, `OneDriveSetup.exe` and registry entries to run it automatically, which I'll be eliminating, using the [File System Security PowerShell Module](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/1abd77a5-9c0b-4a2b-acef-90dbb2b84e85) and command line registry editor, `reg.exe`. Of course, this can be done manually or with other command line tools, if preferred.
        - `takeown /F $mountdir\Windows\SysWOW64\OneDriveSetup.exe /A`
        - `Add-NTFSAccess -Path "$($mountdir)\Windows\SysWOW64\onedrivesetup.exe" -Account "BUILTIN\Administrators" -AccessRights FullControl`
        - `Remove-Item $mountdir\Windows\SysWOW64\onedrivesetup.exe`
        - `reg load HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\WIM $mountdir\Users\Default\ntuser.dat`
        - `reg delete "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\WIM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v OneDriveSetup /f`
     2. The installer shortcuts that Windows 10 creates on the Start Menu.

        - These are controlled by a registry key called "CloudContent", which we'll need to create and add a value to disable, when editing an install disc. If dealing with an existing install, the key would already be created.
        - `reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\WIM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CloudContent`
        - `reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\WIM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CloudContent /v DisableWindowsConsumerFeatures /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f`
        - `reg unload HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\WIM`
     3. The Metro/UWP/Appx applications.

        - We can use the [Get-AppxProvisionedPackage cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852131.aspx) to view and decide which Appx applications to remove.  (`Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -Path $mountdir`) Importantly, not all the pre-installed Appx apps can or should be removed.  As of the time of this writing, it is recommended to not uninstall the AppConnector, ConnectivityStore, and WindowsStore (their use can be disabled in other ways, if desired, but actually removing them has been reported to break things and create undesired consequences).  Also worth noting that in Windows 10, the Windows Calculator is an Appx package.
        - I've elected to leave those three apps, the Windows Calculator, and the Microsoft Solitaire Collection installed, and remove everything else, so I end up running:
        - `dism.exe /Image:$mountdir /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:Microsoft.BingNews_4.6.169.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe`
        - `dism.exe /Image:$mountdir /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:Microsoft.BingSports_4.6.169.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe`
        - `dism.exe /Image:$mountdir /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:Microsoft.BingWeather_4.6.169.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe`
        - `dism.exe /Image:$mountdir /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:Microsoft.BingFinance_4.6.169.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe`
        - `dism.exe /Image:$mountdir /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:Microsoft.CommsPhone_1.10.15000.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe`
        - `dism.exe /Image:$mountdir /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:Microsoft.Messaging_1.10.22012.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe`
        - `dism.exe /Image:$mountdir /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:Microsoft.MicrosoftOfficeHub_2015.6306.23501.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe`
        - `dism.exe /Image:$mountdir /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:Microsoft.Office.OneNote_2015.6131.10051.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe`
        - `dism.exe /Image:$mountdir /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:Microsoft.SkypeApp_3.2.1.0_neutral_~_kzf8qxf38zg5c`
        - `dism.exe /Image:$mountdir /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:Microsoft.Windows.Photos_2015.1001.17200.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe`
        - `dism.exe /Image:$mountdir /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:Microsoft.WindowsCamera_2015.1071.40.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe`
        - `dism.exe /Image:$mountdir /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:Microsoft.WindowsPhone_2015.1009.10.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe`
        - `dism.exe /Image:$mountdir /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:Microsoft.WindowsAlarms_2015.1012.20.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe`
        - `dism.exe /Image:$mountdir /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps_2015.6308.42271.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe`
        - `dism.exe /Image:$mountdir /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:Microsoft.WindowsMaps_4.1509.50911.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe`
        - `dism.exe /Image:$mountdir /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:Microsoft.WindowsSoundRecorder_2015.1012.110.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe`
        - `dism.exe /Image:$mountdir /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:Microsoft.XboxApp_2015.930.526.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe`
        - `dism.exe /Image:$mountdir /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:Microsoft.ZuneMusic_2019.6.13251.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe`
        - `dism.exe /Image:$mountdir /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:Microsoft.ZuneVideo_2019.6.13251.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe`
        - `dism.exe /Image:$mountdir /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:Microsoft.Office.Sway_2015.6216.20251.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe`
        - `dism.exe /Image:$mountdir /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:Microsoft.People_2015.1012.106.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe`
        - `dism.exe /Image:$mountdir /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:Microsoft.Getstarted_2.3.7.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe`
        - `dism.exe /Image:$mountdir /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:Microsoft.3DBuilder_10.9.50.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe`
5. Commit the changes and unmount the WIM.

   - `dism.exe /Unmount-Image /MountDir:$mountdir /commit`

---

Just teh codez:

```
$wimfile = "D:\sources\install.wim"
$mountdir = "C:\Temp\W10entDISM"
dism.exe /Mount-Image /ImageFile:$wimfile /Index:1 /MountDir:$mountdir

# Remove Appx Packages
    dism.exe /Image:$mountdir /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:Microsoft.BingNews_4.6.169.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe
    dism.exe /Image:$mountdir /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:Microsoft.BingSports_4.6.169.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe
    dism.exe /Image:$mountdir /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:Microsoft.BingWeather_4.6.169.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe
    dism.exe /Image:$mountdir /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:Microsoft.BingFinance_4.6.169.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe
    dism.exe /Image:$mountdir /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:Microsoft.CommsPhone_1.10.15000.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe
    dism.exe /Image:$mountdir /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:Microsoft.Messaging_1.10.22012.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe
    dism.exe /Image:$mountdir /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:Microsoft.MicrosoftOfficeHub_2015.6306.23501.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe
    dism.exe /Image:$mountdir /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:Microsoft.Office.OneNote_2015.6131.10051.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe
    dism.exe /Image:$mountdir /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:Microsoft.SkypeApp_3.2.1.0_neutral_~_kzf8qxf38zg5c
    dism.exe /Image:$mountdir /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:Microsoft.Windows.Photos_2015.1001.17200.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe
    dism.exe /Image:$mountdir /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:Microsoft.WindowsCamera_2015.1071.40.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe
    dism.exe /Image:$mountdir /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:Microsoft.WindowsPhone_2015.1009.10.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe
    dism.exe /Image:$mountdir /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:Microsoft.WindowsAlarms_2015.1012.20.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe
    dism.exe /Image:$mountdir /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps_2015.6308.42271.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe
    dism.exe /Image:$mountdir /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:Microsoft.WindowsMaps_4.1509.50911.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe
    dism.exe /Image:$mountdir /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:Microsoft.WindowsSoundRecorder_2015.1012.110.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe
    dism.exe /Image:$mountdir /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:Microsoft.XboxApp_2015.930.526.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe
    dism.exe /Image:$mountdir /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:Microsoft.ZuneMusic_2019.6.13251.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe
    dism.exe /Image:$mountdir /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:Microsoft.ZuneVideo_2019.6.13251.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe
    dism.exe /Image:$mountdir /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:Microsoft.Office.Sway_2015.6216.20251.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe
    dism.exe /Image:$mountdir /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:Microsoft.People_2015.1012.106.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe
    dism.exe /Image:$mountdir /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:Microsoft.Getstarted_2.3.7.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe
    dism.exe /Image:$mountdir /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:Microsoft.3DBuilder_10.9.50.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe

# Remove OneDrive Setup 
    takeown /F $mountdir\Windows\SysWOW64\OneDriveSetup.exe /A
    Add-NTFSAccess -Path "$($mountdir)\Windows\SysWOW64\onedrivesetup.exe" -Account "BUILTIN\Administrators" -AccessRights FullControl
    Remove-Item $mountdir\Windows\SysWOW64\onedrivesetup.exe

    reg load HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\WIM $mountdir\Users\Default\ntuser.dat
    reg delete "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\WIM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v OneDriveSetup /f

# Remove Cloud Content
    reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\WIM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CloudContent
    reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\WIM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CloudContent /v DisableWindowsConsumerFeatures /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f

# Unload, Unmount, Commit
reg unload HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\WIM

dism.exe /Unmount-Image /MountDir:$mountdir /commit
```

---

You should now have an ISO and/or wim file that you can use to install Windows 10 without the added crap, or feed into your configuration/deployment management system. A screenclip of the Start Menu from a resulting OS deployment:

[image]

Comment: Does Windows break if you remove Solitaire?

Comment: @MichaelHampton: No, but your users might break Windows if they don't have their Solitaire.

Comment: I like doing this completely breaks the tile interface. What a load of cr@p!

Comment: @MichaelHampton hah, no, but it's a classic on Windows, so I let it stick around.  A Windows client just feels naked without it, and I don't want to be accused of distributing pornography in the corporate image. :)

Comment: Is it not possible to remove Cortana or Edge? I'd want to use Chrome if I ever installed Windows 10, and I don't need/want to explain why I don't want Cortana(and a thousand other W10 settings).

Comment: @cust1992 No, they're both considered core apps and can't be removed using conventional methods.  Ripping them out anyway has been reported to break things.  If you really want to be rid of them, the better approach is to block them from running with something like Applocker or SRPs.

Comment: You can disable Cortana with GP

Answer (score 2):

OneDrive and Cortana can't be removed the normal way. You need to edit the registry to enable hidden packages under "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Components".

I have [built my own tool](http://www.github.com/buildcenter/windowsbuilder) for customizing Windows 10 (tested on Win 10 -1709 Enterprise). It is mostly written in powershell, so might be easier to read and maintain than the more common batch files you get in forums. You can check the code for details.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be deploying Windows 10 LTSB. Enterprise LTSB is a long-term support version of Windows 10 Enterprise released every 2 to 3 years. Basically, this is Windows 10 without the whole app stuff; No Microsoft Store, no Microsoft Edge, no apps at all.

This obviously requires an entirely different ISO. They are supported with security updates for 10 years after their release, and intentionally receive no feature updates.

If you already have a Windows 10 Enterprise E3 (per device) plan via Volume Licensing, you're allowed to download and install Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB.

More details: http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/D/1/2D14FE17-66C2-4D4C-AF73-E122930B60F6/Windows-10-Volume-Licensing-Guide.pdf

If you can't or don't want to change the OS, you should be able to uninstall all apps via PowerShell:

Run as admin:
  Get-AppXProvisionedPackage -Online | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online
  Get-AppxPackage -allusers | Remove-AppxPackage

Run as user:
  Get-AppxPackage | Remove-AppxPackage

Please keep in mind that those commands will uninstall all apps except Cortana, Edge and Microsoft Store. You'll loose the calculator as well by doing so, just for your information.

Comment: Yup, I have ended up deploying LTSB for most uses, unfortunately, the lack of any metro apps makes it unsuitable for some uses... (I want to say maybe the camera  app for laptops, or something like that) 
 and found myself having to deploy some of the metro apps to all the LTSB installs we have.  So, really, the same problem in reverse, but harder, because some of those metro apps we wanted aren't available in the Windows 10 "store", and don't play well with SCCM anyway.  Stupid @&#$ing Microsoft.